# How can I use AJAX to load content in a Lightbox that is dependent on what trigger the user clicks

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, get

I am writing a Lightbox/Thickbox gallery style program and I need to send what the user clicked to load the proper content in the lightbox.

Here are my files:

> **show-hide-lightbox.js** - Ajax Request Loading the content o lightbox.jsp (which I don't remember how to pass variables to)

```
function showLightbox(){
var ajaxObject = null;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    ajaxObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    ajaxObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if(ajaxObject != null){
    ajaxObject.open("GET","lightbox.jsp",true);
    ajaxObject.send();
}else{
    alert("You do not have a compatible browser.")
}
ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("ajaxResult").innerHTML = ajaxObject.responseText;
    }    
};
}

function hideLightbox(){
    document.getElementById("commentFormBG").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("commentFormFG").style.display = "none";
}
```

**lightbox.jsp** (content to load into a div on the html)

```
<div id="commentFormFG">
    <div class="commentFormTitle">Title of Lightbox</div>
</div>
```

**test.html** - just a page that has the div id=ajaxResult for ajax to load into

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=ajaxResult></div>
    <img onclick="showLightbox()" src="http://www.swanderphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/2013Jul06-9917.jpg">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="show-hide-lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And a minimal StyleSheet

```
#commentFormBG{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#commentFormFG{
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}
```

I would like to send the address of the image clicked but my php has gotten really rusty I am not sure what the easiest way to do that would be anymore.  Ideally you click a thumbnail and the large version of the image loads.

Answer (score 0):

LightBox Gallery You can acctually use FancyBox Plugin
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Old FancyBox doesn't work with latest jQuery loaded. Your link offers FancyBox 2.x which is not for free in case of commercial use.